# Is learning a text editor like vi necessary and still worth the time today?

Tags: linux, scripting, editors, vi, ide

I started a new internship where all the servers run on `AIX`. Logging in for the first time I was suprised to see that my favorite text editor `nano` was not installed.

Everyone here uses `vi` not `vim`......just `vi`.

I've tried learning it before and I can do basic text manipulation but I just can't help but wonder.......

Is it worth the time and effort to become proficient in this environment when there are other more modern options that exist?

Why should i write and edit scripts in the terminal rather than booting up a newer and "fancier" IDE with more modern features like auto-completion and syntax highlighting?

**UPDATE**

I want to thank all of you for your input and help. I don't think the labor will be in vain.

Comment: Some systems have `pico` installed instead of nano, can't remember which was first, but they are clones, sorta.

Comment: @tim I'm fairly certain pico was created for and included in pine (the mail program), and nano was created as a gnu clone of it.

Comment: <joke>Make sure you learn `/bin/ed` for the next time you need to rescue your `fstab` and `/usr/bin` won't mount because it's on a separate partition</joke>.  Also, few graphical IDE's come close to offering the feature set of `vim` or `emacs`, and I can usually go off for a coffee break while waiting for the fancy IDE's to start.

Comment: @Tim, pico is PIne COmposer, the editor that came bundled with the pine mail reader. It became quite popular, but pine's restrictive licence made it a bother. nano is a pico clone.

Comment: the real editor we should all be using, is ed: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the whole idea about editors is kinda warped.

I won't claim, that only **I** know what editor to use when. But we are forced to use editors that we aren't particularly fond of, usually.

When using IDE's, we're all forced to use the editor that comes with it. Even though those editors can be tailored a bit, it's not that we can plug-in `vim` as IDE editor.

OK, so it's not like we can use one editor, so does it make sense getting used to `vi`-likes?

I'd say *yes*, but don't make the error of learning as much commands as possible. If you don't need more than one buffer, or split windows in `vim`, don't bother. Just learn what you need!

I use Vim and gVim for larger portions of text, like source codes that are not edited in an IDE, or where I don't have one, for instance for LaTeX.

But when I just want to do a quick edit of some file, and I'm using Gnome, I just edit it with the editor that is the quickest to access, most usually Gedit.

What I mean, is: Yes, get used to it, but don't necessarily buy a book or something. Just so you know your way around when there's nothing else that you can use. And when you do like it, learn some more, and you might switch over to gVim and stuff. Then, buying the book might be a good idea!

Answer (score 10):

Even though they type `vi` or call it vi it may still be vim. And at least vim can do all the "modern" features like auto-completion and syntax-highlighting, too.

It can also mark/copy/paste text using the mouse if you wish. I however prefer vim and the console because I can do 100% of the work without ever taking one hand off the keyboard. Try that with a fancy IDE.

Comment: that's true but in some SO vi is only vi, you have to install vim to have the features in vi.. like OpenSuSe `zypper install vim` and Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install vim`

Comment: `vi` is pretty much what you will find in any UNIX system; even if you don't use it, knowing how to use its basics can save you in an emergency where you can't use anything more sophisticated.

Comment: OK, it's like this: The original `vi` is only used on UNIX systems, when the license fees are paid. Which of course doesn't happen on Linux-es. There is a plethora of vi clones out there. Vim or gVim is just the better known `vi` clone. The probably second best know clone would be `nvi`, which is used on \*BSD. `nvi` is one of the more *simple* `vi`'s out there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think it's worth it.

For instance what if you were creating/editing a bash script? Or peeking inside a text file and making a single-character change, an IDE might not be suitable or be overkill for such simple tasks. `vi/vim` will fire up almost instantaneously.

Also, when accessing a system remotely having a text based editor available is useful.

`vi` is pretty standard on Unix type systems and can be counted to be available. IDEs etc may vary from system to system.

This doesn't mean that IDEs shouldn't be used, just that there are many times when an IDE would not be the first choice for some of the smaller quick tasks.

You might also be surprised what some of your "basic" editors can do. I use `emacs` daily (both under Linux and Windows) for my programming and `eclipse` sometimes too. Each tool has its use.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it should take no more than a few hours to have basic `vi` knowledge. Due to its everywhere nature, it shall save you much more (hours) eventually.

Regarding IDE — well, some consider `vim`/`emacs` to be one of. ;-)

`vi` is just KISS follower. Simple and powerful enough for most sysadmin's task regarding text files. Although, as to me, honestly, I do prefer `vim`. :-)